# How to access variable outside thread without making the variable final

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, assign

How to access variable outside thread without making the variable final?

```
int x=0;
Thread test = new Thread(){
public void run(){
x=10+20+20;   //i can't access this variable x without making it final, and if i make     it.....                   
              //final i can't assign value to it
}
};    
test.start();
```

Comment: I think this is java, and have updated the tags.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you would want to use `ExecutorService.submit(Callable<Integer>)` and then call `Future.get()` to obtain the value. Mutating variable shared by threads require synchronize action e.g. `volatile`, `lock` or `synchronized` key word

```
    Future<Integer> resultOfX = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return 10 + 20 + 20;
        }
    });
    int x;
    try {
        x = resultOfX.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // never happen unless it is interrupted
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        // never happen unless exception is thrown in Callable
    }
```

Comment: If you really need to mutate int shared by threads, you may want to consider AtomicInteger which provides CAS